# How to create the Json schema in python?

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I want to create the below json schema in python.

```
{
    "persons": [
        {
            "city": "Seattle", 
            "name": "Brian",
            "age" : 19
        }, 
        {
            "city": "Amsterdam", 
            "name": "David",
            "age" : 29
        }, 
        {
            "city": "Amsterdam", 
            "name": "David",
            "age" : 19
        }, 
        {
            "city": "Amsterdam", 
            "name": "David",
            "age" : 49
        }, 
        {
            "city": "Amsterdam", 
            "name": "David",
            "age" : 19
        }
    ]
}
```

I have 3 lists.

```
    city=list_city[10::9]
    name=list_names[9::9][::-1]
    age=list_age[11::9]
```

I have spent few hours to accomplish this by list,dict comprehensions, but I at max get just one Json object inside the persons array.

Like this :-

```
{
    "persons": [
        {
            "city": "Seattle", 
            "name": "Brian",
            "age" : 19
        } "age" : 19

    ]
}
```

Which I suspect is because the dictionary is getting updated &  thereby overwriting old values.

How can I achieve the complete json schema ?

Comment: Can you show the structure of `list_city`, `list_names`, `list_age`?

Comment: Please post a MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the dictionary by using a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
city=list_city[10::9]
name=list_names[9::9][::-1]
age=list_age[11::9]
final_data = {'persons':[dict(zip(['city', 'name', 'age'], i)) for i in zip(*[city, name, age])]}
```

Comment: Nice solution +1 :).

Comment: Thank you very much, today i learnt something new & am really happy for that. :)

Comment: @penta glad to help!